# Android searchview adding rows to the listview

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview, android-search

I'm facing an odd situation here, when I search for an item it returns me what I'm searching for, but it is doing something else too, it is adding 2 empty rows to the listview by each character pressed on the search, if I search for example: "fire" it will add 8 empty rows at the end of my listview, why is this happening?

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FragmentClientes extends Fragment implements OnQueryTextListener{


    private boolean searchCheck;
    private List<ClienteModel> clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
    private ListView lv;
    private View rootView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayout footerLinearLayout;
    public FragmentActivity activity;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private String currentQuery = null;
    private ClientViewAdapter ad;
    private ClientSearchViewAdapter ads;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout._fragment_clientes, container, false);

        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));

        return rootView;


    }




    public void gerarToast(CharSequence message) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(getActivity(), message, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(Menus.PROCURAR));
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String submit) {
//                    showResults(submit, 1);
                    return false;

                }

                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String change) {

                    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (searchCheck) {
                        showResults();


                        try {


                            clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
                            Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(getActivity());
                            List Clientes = mRepositorio.getClientes(change, 15, 1);

                            clientes = Clientes;
                            ads = new ClientSearchViewAdapter(getActivity(), this, clientes);

                            lv.addFooterView(footerLinearLayout);

                            lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                                    new LoadMoreClientTask(progressBar, FragmentClientes.this, ad, getActivity()).execute(1);
                                    System.out.println("PAGE " + page);
                                }
                            });

                            new LoadMoreClientTask(progressBar, this, ad, getActivity()).execute(1);

                            lv.setAdapter(ads);


                            System.out.println("Pesquisa: " + clientes);


                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


        }

        searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));

        ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text))
        .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        menu.findItem(Menus.PROCURAR).setVisible(true);

        searchCheck = true;


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case Menus.PROCURAR:
            searchCheck = true;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }



    private void showResults() {

        try {


            progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams progressBarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressBarParams);
            progressBar.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
            footerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            footerLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            footerLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            footerLinearLayout.addView(progressBar);

                lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);

                clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
                ad = new ClientViewAdapter(getActivity(), this, clientes);

                lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
                lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

                lv.setAdapter(ad);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

LoadMoreTask:

```
public class LoadMoreClientTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {

    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener activity;
    private ClientViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<ClienteModel> cliente = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Context context;

    public LoadMoreClientTask(ProgressBar progressBar, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener activity, ClientViewAdapter adapter, Context context){
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... parameters) {
        int npagina = parameters[0];
        cliente= new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

        try {

            Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(context);


            List listaDeClientes = mRepositorio.getClientes("", 5, npagina);

            cliente = listaDeClientes;


            System.out.println("pagina " + npagina);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            adapter.setData(cliente);
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


}
```

getClientes:

```
public List<ClienteModel> getClientes( String consulta, Integer limit, Integer pagina) throws SQLException {

        int offset = pagina * limit - limit;

        System.out.println("OFFSET: "+ offset);


        List<ClienteModel> listaDeRegistros = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

        System.out.println("Consulta: "+ consulta);

        if(consulta.isEmpty()) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaCLIENTES + " WHERE credencial_id = " + mSessao.getString("id_credencial") + " LIMIT " + offset + ", " + limit;

        }else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaCLIENTES + " WHERE (credencial_id = " + mSessao.getString("id_credencial") + ") AND (nome LIKE '%"+consulta+"%') LIMIT " + offset + ", " + limit;
        }

        System.out.println(query);

        try {

            Cursor mCursor = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        ClienteModel mClienteModel = new ClienteModel();

                        mClienteModel.setClientes_id(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.CLIENTES_ID)));
                        mClienteModel.setId_rm(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.ID_RM)));
                        mClienteModel.setCredencial_id(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.CREDENCIAL_ID)));
                        mClienteModel.setNome(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.NOME)));
                        mClienteModel.setTipo(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.TIPO)));
                        mClienteModel.setInformacao_adicional(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.INFORMACAO_ADICIONAL)));
                        mClienteModel.set_criado(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna._CRIADO)));
                        mClienteModel.set_modificado(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna._MODIFICADO)));
                        mClienteModel.set_status(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna._STATUS)));

                        listaDeRegistros.add(mClienteModel);

                    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return listaDeRegistros;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing this because you keep adding the footerView for the query changes.

```
lv.addFooterView(footerLinearLayout);
```

You should add the footerView one time and keep a reference to it in the Activity and then update the view as needed.

Comment: Can I just remove it?

Comment: Sure, if you don't want it.

Comment: I mean, the endless listview will work fine without it, right?